Deriving a formula from a graph, or whether not a graph represents a square root function
Doing grade 12 functions and physics.
In physics we’re learning vectors. The question involved a box on a slope. Since the force of gravity points directly down, it needs to be broken down into its horizontal and vertical components. We called the force of gravity pulling the box parallel down the slope the horizontal component. The force of friction needs to be equal to this in magnitude (and opposite in direction) if the box is to remain still.
In any case, I became curious how much frictional force is required to hold the box in place at different slope angles. And I noticed that the relationship is not linear:
(I assumed the total force of gravity on the box was 18,000 N, so it weighs about 1,836 kg.)
x = slope angle
y = frictional force required to hold box in place
(10º, 3125 N), (20º, 6156 N), (30º, 9000 N), (40º, 11,570 N)
I then plotted this on a graph, and it looked like a square root function. But when I tried a method of generating the square root formula when given a graph, it did not work.
Question: Does this set of data points represent a square root function? If not, how can you tell? If so, how do you derive the formula when given a graph or set of data points?

It sounds like you were trying to interpolate. Instead, consider regression/least-squares.

I apologize, I don't know what either of those terms mean. I've only done functions, and not calculus, if that's what you're talking about?

@rde -- You calculated the frictional force required to hold box in place with a formula, didn't you? -- henc you do have a formula, what apart from this are you looking for?

Please also include your "method of generating the square root formula" in your original post, as this will help to frame my answer.

How do you know the relationship is not linear? Your four data points do not lie exactly on a line, but if you plot them in Excel, for example, and add a trend line, you can see that the linear model does fit the data reasonably well.

The method of generating the square root formula was f(x) = a√x-h + k, where a is the rise/run between point 1 and 2, and (h,k) is the (x,y) value of the first point (the origin, I think it's called). So a was 6156-3125/20-10, or 303.1, while (h,k) was (10, 3125). This method works for other graphs I tested, eg, the graph for f(x) = √x + 5.

An easy way to eliminate potential classes of function: Check extreme cases. I.e.: What are the forces at 0° and 90°? What kinds of function can achieve that?

I did calculate the frictional force, yes. I was just explaining how I got the data set. Sorry if the framing was poor. I'm interested in being able to know if a set of data points are square root just by looking at the overall graph shape, and, if that is possible, deriving the square root formula from those data points.

The relationship isn't linear, though, and the method used for calculating them is not imprecise. Sin(x) = y/r, when r is the total force of gravity and the angle x is know. Y is the frictional force.

@rde -- Ok, got it: you computed with formula $r\cdot\sin(x)=Y$ a list of value pairs and use this table to find the used formula, just as exercise. I recommend (as GraffL suggested) to add points at $0°$ and $90°$ and ensure in your formula-finding evaluation they are fixed since they are exact as the point at $30°$ too (BTW). Something similarly linear regression of a straight line forced to include $(0, 0)$. Good luck!

You should show how you generated your data (which formulas did you use) and show a visual diagram so that we can interpret what the angle 10 degrees etc refers to.
